# When i try to hover on the second sub-item its closing - Jquery or css issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-hover

Hi I have a menu with sub menus on it. My goal is when user hover on each main menu and if has submenu it will show which i have dome it, problem now is that when you try to hover or select the second sub item it will the jquery hide will kick in and it will hide the whole sub item please.

Here is the js script

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //Main-header-menu desktop
    var subMenu = jQuery('.sub-menu');
    var menuItem = jQuery('.menu-item');
    // hover effect to show sub items
    menuItem.on({mouseenter:function(){
        jQuery(this).find(subMenu).show()
    },mouseleave:function(){
        subMenu.hide(500);
    }
        })
})
```

Here is css

```
 ul#main-menu{
        padding:0;
        margin:10px 0 0 0;
}

ul#main-menu li{
    list-style: none;
    margin:0 0 0 5px;
}

ul#main-menu > li{
    float: left;
}

ul#main-menu li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000000;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-right:1px solid #e5f2ff;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}
ul#main-menu li.menu-item-14{
    border:none;
}
ul#main-menu li.menu-item-14 a {
    font-size: 25px;
}
ul#main-menu li.menu-item ul.sub-menu{
    display: none;
}
```

And the html:

```
    <ul id="main-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-4"><a href="http://localhost/newstt/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-7"><a href="http://#">Hotels</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8"><a href="http://#">Flights</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-9"><a href="http://#">Holiday Packages</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-15"><a href="http://#">Flights + Hotels (Depart from UAE)</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-16"><a href="http://#">Hotels + Tours &#038; Excursions</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-10"><a href="http://#">Tours &#038; Attractions</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17"><a href="http://localhost/newstt/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-11" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11"><a href="http://#">Car Rental</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-12"><a href="http://#">Visas</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13"><a href="http://#">Travel Extras</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-14"><a href="http://#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is [link](http://codepen.io/reside/pen/zByBQP) for the codepen example

Comment: Why not to use the jQuery UI Menu? https://jqueryui.com/menu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submenu items (li) have "menu-item" class. It causes the problem, because the same class is used for first-level menu.
Replace class for submenu items to "menu-subitem" for example and it will be working well.

For example:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-subitem ..."><a href="#">Flights +Hotels (Depart from UAE)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i ended up like like dis $(#main-menu > li) to select only the first level menu. thank you it works now

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because the mouseleave is triggered by the item you leave to go in another one, so all the menu are closed has soon as the one which would appear is open.

I'm on my phone and can't test it to be sure so it's just a suposition, hope it will helps. =/

Comment: Hi Tisamu, i tried event the shorthad method hover(fn1,fn2), but it doesnt solve it.

Comment: Just change the way you think about the menu mechanisme

You want that a menu appear next to the one you hover, and hide it only if you mouse leave this menu OR the child menu (the one which appeared), here your problem is that you leave your menu to go to the child's one, so the first disappear and what's inside with it.

It's a Menu-ception thing but anyway..